# How to inject and use Serilog (Ilogger) when web-api startup

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog, ilogger

I'm developing a **.NET core 3.1 Console application (web-api)**.
I use a **Serilog** service (it is basically using the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging).
The Serilog is injected and can be used in the FW Controllers methods.
Now - I need something a little bit different - Whenever the system is starting up (after being down) I need to make an http post request - you can see it when executing the **ConnectionInitiator.Initiate()**, in the **startup** method. In that same scope (method\class) - I need to use the logger, in order to log some data. Now - If the request would be through the controller - the logger, would be available (by the **DI**).
To make a long story short - I need somehow to inject the Ilogger to the class or to make it available in some other way. I've tried use the logger in the startUp, but this seems to be impossible (since .net core 3.0 - if I understand correctly)
See my code:

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var loggerConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
            //Reading the appconfig.json
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(loggerConfig).CreateLogger();
            try
            {
                Log.Information("System Started up");
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "THE APPLICATION FAILED TO START UP");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }

        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
            }).UseSerilog().UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

StartUp.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration/*, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger*/)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        ConnectionInitiator.Initiate(configuration/*, logger*/);
    }


    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true).AllowCredentials());
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

ConnectionInitiator.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AAA.BL
{
    public static class ConnectionInitiator
    {

        private static readonly object threadlock = new object();
        private static MyConfig myConfig;
        private static ILogger ilogger;
        /*
        public ConnectionInitiator(ILogger _logger)
        {
            ilogger = _logger;
        }
        */
        public static void/*async Task*/ Initiate(IConfiguration configuration/*, ILogger ilogger*/)
        {
            HttpRequester httpRequester = new HttpRequester();
            if (myConfig == null)
            {
                myConfig = new myConfig(configuration);
            }

            IssueOTPResponse response = /*await*/ httpRequester.PostSomething(myConfig, ilogger).Result;            //Double check thread safe singleton implementation
            if (response.ststuacode != 200)
            {
                ilogger.logcritical($"critical error when initiate connection (connectioninitiator): {response.statusdescription}");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answer is much simpler that I expected - By using the **Serilog** and was added as a service in the **Configure** method - It can be reached globally (in every place of the namepsace) by using the static class Log and its static method Logger, for example:
Log.Logger.Information("XXXXX");